# How can i step in and out of this loop?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I'm write a small program to audit a table.

When a column/row is updated in todays data and doesn't match yesterdays. It runs a program to add a end date and then a new row with a start day.

I want it to loop round into there are no more rows left

I'm struggling to get my head around the TSQL loops.. can anyone help me?

```
    DECLARE 
    @new_date date,
    @change_id int 
    while @@rowcount = 1
    begin
    select distinct @change_id = chrows.id , 
    @new_date = chrows.[dw_from_date], 
    @rowid = chrows.row
    from (
    ------------------------------ get data 13648
    SELECT getdate() [dw_from_date]
    ,'9999-01-01 00:00:00.000' [dw_to_date]
    ,prd.[id]en
    FROM [rhehdv].[dbo].[rda_Account] bi
    join [rda].[dbo].[Account] prd on bi.id = prd.id
    where prd.[versionNo] != bi.[versionNo]
    and bi.dw_to_date = '9999-01-01 00:00:00.000'
    ) chrows;
    ----------------------------- old row
    update rhehdv.dbo.[rda_Account]
    set dw_to_date = @new_date
    where id = @change_id
    ------------------------------ new row
    insert into rhehdv.dbo.[rda_Account]
    select @new_date [dw_from_date], 
    '9999-01-01 00:00:00.000' [dw_to_date]
    , a.* 
    from rda.dbo.Account a
    where a.id = @change_id
```

I've not write a TSQL loop before so struggling from the info availible to get my head around, looping, stepping in and out of the loop

Comment: This has a lot of problems.   You should start with a fetch loop to a single table.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/declare-cursor-transact-sql

Comment: thanks man .. but the Micrsoft lay out of how to doesn't really help my with my word dyslexia... which i why I'm asking. To be honest I'm just looking for a example of an loop that can deal with a un specified amount of rows.

Comment: And that link has EXACTLY that.  SE is for specific problems.   You also need to learn how to break down a problem.  You were in a hole and just kept digging.

Comment: oh and can pass the varible to allow a update then a insert.

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. It's helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers. Note that `tsql` narrows the choices, but does not specify the database.

Answer (score 0):

figured it out myself thanks.

```
DECLARE 
@new_date date,
@change_id int, 
@countstop int 
set @countstop = 1
while @countstop > 0
begin
select @change_id = chrows.id , @new_date = chrows.[dw_from_date]
from (
-------------------------------------- select data

----------------------------- update old row from varible
------------------------------ insert new row from varible
        ;
------------------------------ count row and pass as @countstop
end
```